# Cannot connect to 2.4G Wi-Fi from Linux laptop

Tags: linux, wifi

I have TP-Link WiFi router where I have enabled 2.4GHz and 5GHz. Suddenly, I find out, I cannot connect to 2.4G from my laptop, so I started investigating. From my phone, I am able to connect without any problem. When I tried to connect from laptop I receive dialog with reenter password request.

I found out two suspicious things.

First one, from `dmesg` it looks like it is authenticated but it failed on association.

```
$ dmesg -T -w
[So lis 27 14:37:11 2021] wlp5s0: authenticate with d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4
[So lis 27 14:37:11 2021] wlp5s0: send auth to d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4 (try 1/3)
[So lis 27 14:37:11 2021] wlp5s0: authenticated
[So lis 27 14:37:11 2021] wlp5s0: associate with d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4 (try 1/3)
[So lis 27 14:37:11 2021] wlp5s0: associate with d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4 (try 2/3)
[So lis 27 14:37:11 2021] wlp5s0: associate with d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4 (try 3/3)
[So lis 27 14:37:11 2021] wlp5s0: association with d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4 timed out
[So lis 27 14:37:22 2021] wlp5s0: authenticate with d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4
[So lis 27 14:37:22 2021] wlp5s0: send auth to d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4 (try 1/3)
[So lis 27 14:37:22 2021] wlp5s0: authenticated
[So lis 27 14:37:22 2021] wlp5s0: associate with d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4 (try 1/3)
[So lis 27 14:37:22 2021] wlp5s0: associate with d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4 (try 2/3)
[So lis 27 14:37:22 2021] wlp5s0: associate with d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4 (try 3/3)
[So lis 27 14:37:23 2021] wlp5s0: association with d8:07:b6:2b:ae:e4 timed out
```

Second, I let the wireshark to capture everything on my wireless interface, but there is nothing captured on 2.4G band. I tried it with my 5G network and it works fine, wireshark has been able to capture packets.

I checked MAC Address of Wi-Fi router, it's OK. My laptop is not on blacklist and in syslog of router, there is nothing.

I create a hotspot from my mobile phone on 2.4G band, and it works nicely. I could see logs in wireshark and dmesg too.

From my point of view, my PC is able to use 2.4G Wi-Fi, my Wi-Fi router works, but my PC cannot connect to it (only to 5G works).

I also update and upgrade system.

How can I debug this issue and find out the root cause and fix it?

Comment: Bluetooth interference? They work on same Band. Its not fix but try turning down bluetooth and see if works to see if its the cause.

Comment: Is "suddenly" related to some upgrades you did on your computer? If yes, I'd suspect firmware/driver issues.

Comment: one debugging technique, have you tried to connect to it with more distance, where the 5Ghz breaks, and 2.4 is still good?  Sometimes these devices choose 5 over 2.4, by default, and im also wondering if maybe its the router also bumping it because of this, which wouldn't be nice.

Comment: can you test with WPA2/WPA3 ?

Comment: I tryied turn of bluetooth, the same result. Suddenly - no after upgrade. Most of the time, I am on cable or near wifi (4m) so I prefer 5G. From time to time, I move to the room  where 5G signal is weak (distance and walls) and I figure out I cannot connect to 2G, even when I am in front of router. I tested to manually remove 5G network and test only with 2G - does not help, With other devices like phone or other notebook (windows) it works fine.

Comment: WPA2/WPA3 - I am using security `WPA/WPA2-Personal` option. Version and Encyprion set to Auto. I can see on 5G setting, there is `WPA2-PSK`. Mode is `802.11b/g/n mixed`, channel width 20MHz. I do not change anything and only my laptop has this issue.

Comment: I just tested it with bootable ubuntu USB, and I cannot connect to 2G too. I would suspected router but there is no errors and also, there is issue only with association process as you can see from logs.

Comment: Have you tried enabling IPV4?

Comment: @JeremyBoden what do you mean enabling IPv4? I am using 192.168.0.x range.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW i had the same problem on 5.15 kernel on an Ubuntu 22.04 and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608889/16764) post helped, but note the updated option syntax so i added the comment and options line

```
# fix for 2.4ghz
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and rebooted and it worked for this one specific AP on 2.4GHz.

Some further suggestions can be found in [this thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=363710) but unfortunately its locked by now.